# JavaFX “Location is required." i have tried all solutions

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

i need to execute a jar file of javafx application ,i can't solve this problem , when i execute in the IDE it work normally 
this is my main

```
public class Main extends Application { 
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Contrlpanel.FXML"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,487,406);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/fxml/application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}}
```

the structure :

[image]

and the problem :
[image]

please help me..

Comment: Show your directory structure.

Comment: You're not accessing your fxml file correctly, or, your css file.

Comment: is your fxml file really named "Contrlpanel.fxml"? It looks like it could be a typo of "Controlpanel.fxml", because it's just missing an O.

Comment: @MMAdams no the name of fxml is true Contrlpanel

Comment: @SamOrozco the structre is included now

Comment: What kind of machine are you on? Have you tried? `../fxml/Contrlpanel.FXML`

Comment: yes i have used the path it work with or without  path in the IDE but when i export it as jar file dont work

Comment: Ahhh yes. I had the same issue .

Comment: I don't recall how but you need to indicate which files you want to copy in the compilation.